# Which design pattern to apply when using Redis as a datastore with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I'm thinking about using Redis for storing things I don't want to pull out of the database, user counts, follower ids, long urls that Rails has to spit out ... etc and I'm trying to figure out a way to design my app to do this.

I was wondering if to take the approach that redis is a persistent datastore that I have to load up before I run the app.

So something like

```
Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   def thumbnail_url
      #get redis value
   end
end
```

or should I actually be thinking of Redis as a more transient kind of storage where I would do the same thing like this

```
Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   def thumbnail_url
      if redis value exists
         get it
      else
         do some ruby stuff and return string #hit Active record
      end
   end
end
```

Or is there another way I should be thinking about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you seen this gem? https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects, this will help with active record.

Comment: Yes I just did, the problem is that there doesn't seem to be a way to initialize values. So I can't see a way to make ... say ... post.redis_thumbnail_url return a value from ActiveRecord if it isn't already in Redis.

Comment: Sounds like you need a NullObject design pattern http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/12179019201/design-patterns-in-the-wild-null-object